# Recursive sql with Left outer join in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, recursive-query

I have a query that is using `Table1` and `Table2` with left outer join on `'usage'`. Now i have to join that query with the `Table3` with (I guess recursive sql) to generate the `'Resulting table'`.

I saw lot of examples on recursive sql, but didnt find any thing that is using left outer join.
 Now my existing query is like this

```
     select PIN,  startDt,  StartTm,  usage,  Min 
     from Table1 t1 left Outer join Table2 t2 on t1.usage= t2.usage;
```

How can i do the `Table3` with this query, so that ratGrp will be in comma separated way? Please help!!

```
     Table1
     PIN  startDt  StartTm  usage  Min
     -----------------------------------------
     123 08/03/2014 12:12:00 500  4567
     234 08/04/2014 12:12:00 200  4568
     .....
     Table2
     1stCol  2ndCol  usage
      ------------------------
     abc        234      500

    Table3
    PIN   ratGrp
    -----------------
    123   3300
    123  100
    123  103
    234  3300
    234  550

    Resulting table
    PIN startDt  StartTm  usage  Min  ratGrp
    -----------------------------------------------
    123 08/03/2014 12:12:00 500  4567   3300,100,103
    234 08/04/2014 12:12:00 200  4568   3300,550
```

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595182/sql-concatenate-multiple-rows

Comment: @Sathish, Thanks for your replay. I might be wrong but i think volatile table is active till the session is active. we can't change that with in a span of session after it is created. the query that i am working on is a web page query. The query changes depending on the search criteria entered by the users. and there will be different search criteries in one perticular session, i might need different types of volatile table, which doesnt sound me the perfect solution. Please guide me if i am wrong.

Comment: What version of Teradata?