# XMLAGG EQUIVALENT in Teradata 16

Tags: sql, teradata

Is there any EQUIVALENT function of `"XMLAGG"`, as performance of `XMLAGG` is very bad.

sample:sql

```
SELECT 
            LOAN_APLCTN_KEY

        ,CAL.COB_DT AS STRT_DT
        ,CAL.NXT_COB_DATE AS END_DT
        ,CAL.COB_RUN_END_TM

    ,TRIM(TRAILING '0A'XC FROM (XMLAGG(TRIM(FREE_MEMO)|| '0A'XC ORDER BY M_INDX ASC) (VARCHAR(2500) , CHARACTER SET UNICODE ) ) ) AS FREE_MEMO
    FROM 
        (
              SELECT A.* ,
            A.NXT_WRKG_DY AS NXT_COB_DATE
            FROM BUSNSVLT_VW.BV_COB_DATES  A            
            WHERE CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2019-11-01' AND DATE '2019-11-10'
           QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY COB_DT,   COB_RUN_END_TM ORDER BY COB_DT  DESC  ) =1

        ) CAL
    INNER JOIN  
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM DATAVLT_VW.T24_SAT_LOAN_APLCTN_FREE_MEMO  AA
        WHERE  M_INDX >0  
        AND PERIOD ( CAST ( DATE '2019-11-01'   - INTERVAL '1' DAY AS TIMESTAMP (6)  )   , CAST (  DATE '2019-11-10'     + INTERVAL '1' DAY AS TIMESTAMP (6) )   ) 
      OVERLAPS ( AA.LD_DT , AA.LD_ENDDT  )
    )AA
    ON  CAL.COB_RUN_END_TM BETWEEN AA.LD_DT AND AA.LD_ENDDT
    GROUP BY LOAN_APLCTN_KEY
                ,CAL.COB_DT 
                ,CAL.NXT_COB_DATE 
                ,CAL.COB_RUN_END_TM
```

Comment: can you tell where you encountered `XMLAGG` ..? in Oracle or DB2 or else..?

Comment: Hi Ozhan,Teradata 15

Comment: If you need ordered aggregation the fastest way is probably still good ol' aggregation https://stackoverflow.com/a/19606458/2527905